# Why am I getting "invalid conversion from const pointer to pointer?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, linked-list, type-conversion

I'm working with a linked list, specifically I am trying to append an object.
The append function is passed a pointer to the object I want to add.

This pointer is then used in the initialization of a OULink (a list node) object.

Inside my OULink class, I am trying to set the data pointer to = the object I am trying to add, and that is where I am getting an error:

error: invalid conversion from 'const NvraRecord*' to 'NvraRecord*' [-fpermissive]
  this->data = item;

I thought since they were both of type T* I could assign one to the other.

```
template <typename T>
class OULinkedList {
    template <typename F>
    friend class OULinkedListEnumerator;
private:
    Comparator<T>* comparator = NULL;               // used to determine list order and item equality
    unsigned long size = 0;                         // actual number of items currently in list
    OULink<T>* first = NULL;                        // pointer to first link in list
    OULink<T>* last = NULL;                         // pointer to last link in list
public:
    OULinkedList(Comparator<T>* comparator);        // creates empty linked list with comparator
    virtual ~OULinkedList();                        // deletes all links and 
template <typename T>
bool OULinkedList<T>::append(const T* item) {


    if(this->first == NULL){

        OULink<NvraRecord> currentNode(item);
        this->first = &currentNode;

    }else{

    }
    std::cout << *this->first->data << std::endl;
    return false;
}



template <typename T>
class OULink {
    template <typename F>
    friend class OULinkedList;
    template <typename F>
    friend class OULinkedListEnumerator;
private:
    T* data = NULL;                                     // pointer to data item of any type
    OULink* next = NULL;                                // pointer to next link
public:
    OULink(const T* item);
    virtual ~OULink();
};

template<typename T>
OULink<T>::~OULink(){

}
// Implementation goes here
template<typename T>
OULink<T>::OULink(const T* item){

    this->data = item;
}
```

Comment: You can't assign `const T *` to `T *`. To allow it would allow you to then modify a `const` object. If `const int * x` points to a `const int i`, then if you assigned the pointer a non-const pointer with `int * y = x;` you could then use `y` to try to modify `i`.

Comment: "I thought since they were both of type T* I could assign one to the other." They are not both of type `T*`. One is of type `T const *`.

Comment: @Swordfish Well, I had originally thought that they were both the same but you could not modify the contents of the const T*.

Comment: `this->first = &currentNode;` is a bug, you store the address of a local variable which is immediately destroyed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `OULink` constructor takes a `const T* item`, which is a pointer to a const T.  `OULink.data` can store a `T*`, which is a pointer to a non-const T.

You cannot assign a `const T*` to a `T*`, because the `const` is a contract that says "I will not let the object I am pointing to change."  If you could assign to a `T*`, that pointer would allow the object to be modified, which would break that contract.

You probably want to change the constructor `OULink(const T* item);` to `OULink(T* item);`.

Comment: So, I am unable to modify any declarations. However, I did find a work around by using const_cast<T*>(item) but I'm not sure if this was the intended point or if there has been a mistake by our instructor.

Comment: If you use a `const_cast<>` to overcome a mistake your instructor made you should add a note that modifying a `const` object is undefined behaviour: http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.type.cv#4

Comment: Possibly it is intended that the pointed-to input item be copied?

Comment: `const_cast` is the devil.  Not as bad as the C Preprocessor (which is THE DEVIL), but still quite evil.